# How can I add a custom row to the end of my query results

Tags: azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

I have a simple query for reporting.

```
requests
| project name
```

which gives me:

```
name
----
foo
bar
baz
```

I want to modify the query to add an extra row, so something like:

```
requests
| project name
| print("qux")
```

which would give:

```
name
----
foo
bar
baz
qux
```

Is this possible? I can't just add actual data, and the real reason is for reporting purposes. I just need to write a query that will give me the last results I listed above.

Comment: You can use UNION ALL in query

Comment: Give more details. MySQL or SQL etc..?

Comment: Application insights. I think it’s distinct from SQL

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom table with the row you want using 'datatable', and then use the 'union' operator to append the row:

```
let x = datatable (name:string) [ "qux" ];
requests
| take 5
| project name 
| union x
```

Also possible to start with a 'print':

```
print("qux")
| project-rename name=print_0
| union (requests | take 5 | project name)
```